# Having the arsclassica titles shape using classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis

I am using classicthesis and I would like to customize the shape of the titles in the way [arsclassica](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arsclassica) does. How can I do it ? This is a view of what I am searching for : [image]

This is my preamble :

```
 `% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage[tight,french]{minitoc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{../classicthesis} %,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\renewcommand\textflush{flushright}
```

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newlength\epitextskip
\pretocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@epitext}{\em}{}{}
\patchcmd{\epigraph}{\@epitext{#1}\}{\@epitext{#1}\[\epitextskip]}{}{}
\makeatother

\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
\setlength\epitextskip{2ex}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}

\FrenchFootnotes
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lineno}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}}
\frontmatter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%modifie la taille des numéros de     chapitres%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@eulerchapternumbers}}% font for the chapter numbers
{\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{eur}\fontseries{b}\fontsize{28}  {29}\selectfont}}%
{\newcommand\mychapterNumber{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pplj}\fontsize{25}{26}\selectfont}}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
    {\relax}{\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
}{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
    {\relax}{{\color{halfgray}\mychapterNumber\thechapter}}{1.2em}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }
    \begin{document}
%   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%   \manualmark
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

`` \pagestyle{scrheadings}`<code> ``

Comment: You can easily do that with the `titlesec` package if it is not incompatible with classic thesis.

Comment: `arsclassica` uses `classicthesis` internally or rather is based on `classicthesis`, why not using `arsclassica`?

Comment: @ Johannes_B : Because I do not like `arsclassica` fonts and do not know exactly how to change it.

Comment: Hint: do omit the space between the @ and the name ;-) @domi Otherwise the user isn't pinged. Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we can see the basic setup? It might just be a copy/paste from arsclassica to your preamble.

Comment: Just copy the code in `arsclassica.sty` from line 81 to 146 inclusive, paste it in your preamble (between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatothe`, just to be sure) and remove all the `\sffamily` commands.

Comment: Thanks, but sorry it does not work in this way.

Comment: @domi If you have further questions, editing the answer is surely not the path to follow. Add a comment asking what you need, or open a new question with the details.

Comment: OK. Did you see the previous questions I asked ? It was about the changes I made into my preamble. Is my new preamble correct ? It was also about the following issue : now, when I have a title which is composed of more than 6 words, there is no more space between the title and the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the code from line 81 to 146 inclusive of `arsclassica.sty` and paste it into your preamble, removing all `\sffamily` commands.

Remove the setting to `\descriptionlabel`, which is in that part of the code, but really doesn't belong there, and redefine `\chapterNumber`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis} %,manychapters

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\makeatletter % <---- important
%%% from arsclassica.sty
% parts
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@parts}}%
        {%
    \titleformat{\part}[display]
        {\normalfont\centering\large}%
        {\thispagestyle{empty}\partname~\MakeTextUppercase{\thepart}}{1em}%
        {\color{Maroon}\spacedallcaps}
    }{\relax}
    % chapters
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}%
    {%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]%             
        {\relax}{\raggedleft{\color{halfgray}%
        \chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}%
        {\titlerule\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright%
        \spacedallcaps}%
        [\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
    }{%  
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block]%
        {\normalfont\Large}%
        {{\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter%
        \hspace{10pt}\vline}  }{10pt}%
        {\spacedallcaps}}
    % sections
    \titleformat{\section} 
          {\normalfont\Large}{\textsc%
          {\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}%
         {1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
    % subsections
    \titleformat{\subsection}
        {\normalfont}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase%
        {\thesubsection}}}{1em}{\normalsize}
    % subsubsections
    \titleformat{\subsubsection}
        {\normalfont\itshape}{\textsc%
        {\MakeTextLowercase{\thesubsubsection}}}%
        {1em}{\normalsize\itshape}        
    % paragraphs
    \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
        {\normalfont\normalsize}{\textsc%
        {\MakeTextLowercase{\theparagraph}}}%
        {0pt}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
    % descriptionlabels
    \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}%
    \bfseries\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}%
    {2\baselineskip}
    \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2\baselineskip}%
    {.8\baselineskip}[\marginparsep]
    \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.5\baselineskip}%
    {.8\baselineskip}[\marginparsep]
    \titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}%
    {1\baselineskip}
    %
    \newcommand\formatchapter[1]{% 
    \vbox to \ht\strutbox{ 
    \setbox0=\hbox{\chapterNumber\thechapter\hspace{10pt}\vline\ } 
    \advance\hsize-\wd0 \advance\hsize-10pt\raggedright 
    \spacedallcaps{#1}\vss}} 
    \titleformat{\chapter}[block] 
       {\normalfont\Large} 
       {\textcolor{halfgray}{\chapterNumber\thechapter} 
       \hspace{10pt}\vline\ }{10pt} 
    {\formatchapter}    
        %
        \if@twoside\rofoot[\mbox{\makebox[0pt][l]{\kern1em\thepage}}]{}\fi
\makeatother % <----- important

\renewcommand\chapterNumber{\fontsize{50}{0}\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Ouverture}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If all you want is changing the chapter headings, remove all that doesn't refer to chapters.

Here's the reduced version:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage[parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc,eulerchapternumbers]{classicthesis} %,manychapters

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\makeatletter
%%% from arsclassica.sty
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}
  {1\baselineskip}
  {2\baselineskip}

\newcommand\formatchapter[1]{% 
  \vbox to \ht\strutbox{ 
    \setbox0=\hbox{\chapterNumber\thechapter\hspace{10pt}\vline\ } 
    \advance\hsize-\wd0 \advance\hsize-10pt\raggedright 
    \spacedallcaps{#1}\vss}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\Large}
  {\textcolor{halfgray}{\chapterNumber\thechapter} \hspace{10pt}\vline\ }
  {10pt}
  {\formatchapter}    

\if@twoside\rofoot[\mbox{\makebox[0pt][l]{\kern1em\thepage}}]{}\fi
\makeatother

\renewcommand\chapterNumber{\fontsize{50}{0}\usefont{U}{eur}{b}{n}}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\chapter{Ouverture}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works well ! But I see two things that does not fit my needs : first, the size of the first section is bigger than in classic thesis; second, the style of the subsection is not in italics as classic thesis does.

Comment: @domi As I said, remove the parts that don't deal with chapters from the added code. I added the reduced version.